# Is it possible to create table of JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

Is it possible to create table of JFormattedTextField?

```
JFormattedTextField field [][]  = new JFormattedTextField();
                    field.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50); 
                    panel.add(field[2][2]);
```

And then `field[2][2].getText()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want a 2 dimensional array containing 2500 `JFormattedTextField` then try:

```
JFormattedTextField field [][] = new JFormattedTextField[50][50];

for (int i=0;i<field.length;i++) {
   for (int j=0;j<field[i].length;j++) {
     field[i][j]=new JFormattedTextField();
   }
}
```

I doubt you really want that though...

Read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem